"Failed to load module script" on import Splide
I would like to use the Splide library. I created a test folder in which I copied and pasted the code provided on the Splide platform :
import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';


new Splide( '.splide' ).mount();

<section class="splide" aria-label="Splide Basic HTML Example">
  <div class="splide__track">
        <ul class="splide__list">
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 01</li>
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 02</li>
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 03</li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>

I get this error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@splidejs/splide". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
I corrected the path:
import Splide from './node_modules/@splidejs/splide';
but I get another error that I can't resolve:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@splidejs/splide". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
I use fiveserver extension in vscode
Thanks
I tried changing source folder and changing path.
After searching on the net, I applied this code:
import '@splidejs/splide'
it does not work

If you are using import '@splidejs/splide' directly in the browser, it won't work because the browser does not know about node_modules and the like. Browsers expect the path to point to a file directly (or using some mapping but that just makes things more complex for now). Otherwise you have to compile the code to be web-compatible, which will spit out the imported file instead with something like ESBuild, webpack or Rollup.
